# SwiftUI Textfield click keyborod 'done' not working

Tags: swift, swiftui

I found that when I use this method, click the `done` button on the keyboard, the keyboard will not close automatically:

```swift
struct Test: View {
    
    @State private var currentText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        // this method: init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, text: Binding<String>, axis: Axis)
        TextField("say something...", text: $currentText, axis: .vertical)
            .font(.subheadline)
            .lineLimit(2, reservesSpace: true)
            .padding()
            .submitLabel(.done)
            .border(.red)
    }
}
```

But when I switch to this method, click `done`, the keyboard will automatically close, is this a bug?

```swift
// init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, text: Binding<String>)
TextField("say something...", text: $currentText)
            .font(.subheadline)
            .lineLimit(2, reservesSpace: true)
            .padding()
            .submitLabel(.done)
            .border(.red)
```

I want to be able to use the method with the 'axis' feature, and click 'done' without wrapping automatically, how can this be achieved?

Comment: `submitLabel(.done)` changes what would have been the "return" key to "done". Do you not want users to enter new lines?

Comment: So you don't want the submit label to dismiss keyboard or you do?